# Payment gateway with handle 'wc-payment-method-paypal' has been deactivated because its dependency 'wc-blocks-registry' is not registered

Tags: woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

Using up to date Woo-commerce and WordPress, with built in Paypal checkout - sometimes there is an error:

```
Payment gateway with handle 'wc-payment-method-paypal' has been deactivated because its dependency 'wc-blocks-registry' is not registered. Read the docs about registering assets for payment methods: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/trunk/docs/extensibility/payment-method-integration.md#registering-assets
```

The error is not reproducible, and occurs intermittently.

[Wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-after-last-update-37/) has a thread on the issue, but does not have a solution. Installing the Woocommerce Blocks plugin was suggested as an answer, but was reported to not be the solution.

The suggested `add_action( ‘woocommerce_checkout_order_review’, ‘woocommerce_checkout_payment’, 11);` seems to answer a different problem of their checkout payment options never loading.  This is not the issue as reported by many others on the thread.

What would be causing this error as the dependencies for Paypal should be registered by Woocommerce...

Comment: Sounds stupid but have you tried reinstall WooCommerce? Maybe something went wrong during an update or so.

Comment: I havent. And as I say I cant reproduce the error, it pops up when Im not testing it. So I cant test a reinstall.  The fact that others are having the same problem leads me to think there is a problem with a solution?